# Execute SQL script loaded from a file against an existing SQL Server connection in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, connection

I have a SQL script that I can execute against an existing, connected, SQL Server database in VS Code.

I save the SQL script to a file.

The > run icon in the toolbar changes to a > inside a circle.

When I press that new button I get an error message for the save script which ends with....

> ERROR at line 1:
> Not connected

How do I run this SQL script against the same connection from which it was successfully executed?

Or, another way, I open a SQL file and want to run it using an existing SQL Server database connection: how do I do this?

If I use SSMS there is a connection pulldown in the toolbar but I can see nothing like it in VS Code.

I'm sure this is something trivial but I can't see what is the solution.

Comment: Not relevant to the sql server tag.

Comment: Its not directly an answer to your question but I've always use Azure Data Studio when I wanted to work with SQL Server in VS Code - its basically a version of VS Code dedicated specifically to SQL work. As far as using VSCode goes, I'm not able to visualize what you mean about saving the file (that in itself shouldn't change anything) or what you are saying about these buttons. When you hover over them do they have any tooltips that say what they "are"? Pretty much you should be able to connect the same way you connected originally, right?

Comment: Also I guess just to be sure, you aren't using VSCode in a "notebook" mode, are you?

Comment: No, not in notebook mode.

Comment: I use SQL Developer, SSMS and pgAdmin: yes I'm a database developer.
I'm trying VS Code even though I use SSMS (which I prefer) because Oracle have announced that they are deprecating SQL Developer and are recommending their extension to VS Code. I thought I would try it out.

Comment: There's lots of help filesand blogs out there in google land - that's really the best place to start rather than just trying to click buttons :) Examples: [developer-tools-for-vscode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/developer-tools-for-vscode/getting-started/connectdatabase.html) [oracle-developer-tools-for-vs-code](https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-developer-tools-for-vs-code-f26d31535925)

Comment: It's funny, that was what I did before coming to the forum! Spent an hour or so with Google etc. In the end, I discovered Ctrl-Shift-P/E.